# How to handle dates when the input dates are in the transition period from PDT to PST?

Tags: java

I am calling an API which takes two dates as input.The API checks if the difference between the two date is greater than 60 min, then it throws an exception.My input dates are startDate=11-06-2016T00:57:01  and endDate=11-06-2016T01:56:01.These two dates are saved in java.util.Date object.
Now the issue is though the two dates have a difference of 59 min which is less than 60 min, still the API throws exception.Looks like this isssue is due to DayLightSaving.On Nov 6,once 2 am is reached , DayLightSaving ends (PDT time zone ends), time is moved backward by 1 hr due to which time again become 1 am but in PST time zone now.This means on Nov 6 , there would be 1-2 am twice one in PDT and one in PST zone.
When this API is called on NOV 7, the time zone would be PST.So when the two dates are passed without the timezone specified, it takes the startDate in PDT zone and enddate in PST zone.Since PDT and PST itself have a difference of 1 hour, this would get added to the 59 min differnce and exception is being thrown.
How to handle this case when the input dates are in the transition period from PDT to PST?

sample code

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
String start="11-06-2016 00:57:01";
String end ="11-06-2016 01:56:01";
Date startdate = formatter1.parse(start);
Date enddate = formatter1.parse(end);
System.out.println("startDate is :"  + startdate);
System.out.println("endDate is :"  +enddate);
long dateRange = enddate.getTime() - startdate.getTime();
//if the difference between the two dates is > than 60 min i.e  3600000 ms, then throw exception.
System.out.println(dateRange);
if (dateRange > (60 * 60 * 1000)){
    throw new Exception("Date time range cannot be greater than 60 minutes.(calculated using millisecond difference)");
}
```

Output

```
[Date Range is = 7140000
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Date time range cannot be greater than 60 minutes.(calculated using millisecond difference).
    at Datetest.main(Datetest.java:28)][1]
```

The above snippet throws exception when called in PST time zone.

Comment: If you're using ISO date formats, where date and time are separated by a `T`, you should use the correct `yyyy-MM-dd` order.

Comment: As you found out, the time was 01:56:01 _twice_ on 11/6/2016 in the Pacific time zone.  So before asking "how to handle this case", you need to specify how you want the time 01:56:01 to be interpreted.  By itself, it's ambiguous.  Where is this time coming from, and what information would tell the program whether it's PST or PDT so that it can resolve the ambiguity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `SimpleDateFormat` nor the underlying `Calendar` specifies what happens when parsing a datetime string without timezone for a time in the overlapping hour between daylight savings time and standard time.

You have observed that it will return the later time, i.e. it seems to prefer standard over daylight savings time. But, the behavior is undefined, so...

The new `java.time` classes do however specify exactly what happens, and how to choose the other "hour" of the overlap.

In the new API, since your datetime string is without timezone, you'd likely first parse using `LocalDateTime`, then apply time zone to get a `ZonedDateTime`, e.g.

```
LocalDateTime ldtEnd = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-11-06T01:56:01");
ZonedDateTime zdtEnd = ldtEnd.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
// zdtEnd is now: 2016-11-06T01:56:01-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
```

To see the overlap, you can try adding an hour:

```
ZonedDateTime zdtEnd2 = zdtEnd.plusHours(1);
// zdtEnd2 is now: 2016-11-06T01:56:01-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
```

The behavior is well-defined, see javadoc of [`atZone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-):

> In most cases, there is only one valid offset for a local date-time. **In the case of an overlap**, where clocks are set back, there are two valid offsets. **This method uses the *earlier* offset typically corresponding to "summer"**.
>
> In the case of a gap, where clocks jump forward, there is no valid offset. Instead, the local date-time is adjusted to be later by the length of the gap. For a typical one hour daylight savings change, the local date-time will be moved one hour later into the offset typically corresponding to "summer".
>
> **To obtain the later offset** during an overlap, **call `ZonedDateTime.withLaterOffsetAtOverlap()`** on the result of this method. To throw an exception when there is a gap or overlap, use `ZonedDateTime.ofStrict(LocalDateTime, ZoneOffset, ZoneId)`.

As you can see, it will always return the *earlier* time in an overlap, which is opposite of the observed behavior of `SimpleDateFormat`. If you want the *later* time in an overlap, call `withLaterOffsetAtOverlap()`.

If you don't want to rely on documented default, you can always be explicit:

```
ZoneId PT = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");

LocalDateTime ldtStart = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-11-06T00:57:01");
ZonedDateTime zdtStartEarly = ldtStart.atZone(PT).withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap();
ZonedDateTime zdtStartLater = ldtStart.atZone(PT).withLaterOffsetAtOverlap();
System.out.println(zdtStartEarly); // 2016-11-06T00:57:01-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
System.out.println(zdtStartLater); // 2016-11-06T00:57:01-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

LocalDateTime ldtEnd = LocalDateTime.parse("2016-11-06T01:56:01");
ZonedDateTime zdtEndEarly = ldtEnd.atZone(PT).withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap();
ZonedDateTime zdtEndLater = ldtEnd.atZone(PT).withLaterOffsetAtOverlap();
System.out.println(zdtEndEarly); // 2016-11-06T01:56:01-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
System.out.println(zdtEndLater); // 2016-11-06T01:56:01-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]
```

As you can see, for the `00:57` time, it makes no difference, because that time is not in the overlap hour.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here get the difference between the 2 dates using timezone offset. something like below

```
private int getDSTdifferenceDateAdjustment(Date startDate, Date endDate, TimeZone timeZone)
{
    if (startDate == null || endDate == null) return 0;
    int baseOffset = timeZone.getOffset(startDate.getTime());
    int newOffSet = timeZone.getOffset(endDate.getTime());

    return (newOffSet - baseOffset);
}
```

Have something like this in your method

```
int dstDifference = getDSTdifferenceDateAdjustment(startdate, enddate, TimeZone.getDefault());
// The dstDifference will get in the negative, so we are adding to the dateRange variable
dateRange += dstDifference;
```

Try this one and even check when the DST starts next year. Mostly this will work in all these cases